# mysql slow query that may due to find_in_set function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure which takes 22 seconds to run. The sql query contains find_in_set function, when I removed all the find_in_set functions in sql,the sql runs in 5 seconds. If I use like to subsitute all the find_in_set functions, it still runs in 22 seconds. I am doubting the find_in_set function make the query slow. But I am also doubting there may be other reason. Any way I can improve the query?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SelectTasksByCriteria`(
      IN p_ids MEDIUMTEXT 
    , IN p_taskName nvarchar(255)
    , IN p_delegationName nvarchar(255)
    , IN p_statuses nvarchar(1024)
    , IN p_assignedToUsers nvarchar(1024)
    , IN p_assignedToGroups nvarchar(1024)
    , IN p_dueDateFrom datetime
    , IN p_dueDateTo datetime
    , IN p_createdBy nvarchar(100)
    , IN p_createdDateFrom datetime
    , IN p_createdDateTo datetime
    , IN p_delegationIDs MEDIUMTEXT 
    , IN p_locationIDs MEDIUMTEXT 
    , IN p_language nvarchar(10)
)
BEGIN
    select
        t.id, t.DelegationID
        , case when (select count(lbl.id) from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = t.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'tasks' and lbl.ColumnName = 'TaskName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language and lbl.IsDeleted = 0) > 0 then
            (select content from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = t.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'tasks' and lbl.ColumnName = 'TaskName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language and lbl.IsDeleted = 0 limit 1)
        else
            t.TaskName
        end as TaskName
        , t.DueDate, t.CreatedBy, t.CreatedDate, t.ModifiedBy, t.ModifiedDate, t.IsDeleted
        , (select td.ObjectID from `tasks_details` as td where td.TaskID = t.id limit 1) as `TaskObjectID`
        , (select td.ObjectType from `tasks_details` as td where td.TaskID = t.id limit 1) as `TaskObjectType`
        , d.DelegationName
        , ar.Submitter
        , ar.SubmissionDate
        , case 
            when (
                    t.CreatedDate = t.ModifiedDate
                    and
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is null
                ) then
                204 
            when (
                    t.CreatedDate <> t.ModifiedDate
                    and
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is null
                ) then
                205 
            when (
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is not null
                    and

                    (
                        select ara.ApprovalStatus from `approval_request_approvers` as ara
                        where ara.ApprovalRequestID = rt.ApprovalRequestID and ara.IsDeleted = 0
                        order by ara.ModifiedDate desc limit 1
                    ) = 202
                ) then
                202 
            when (
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is not null
                    and

                    (
                        select ara.ApprovalStatus from `approval_request_approvers` as ara
                        where ara.ApprovalRequestID = rt.ApprovalRequestID and ara.IsDeleted = 0
                        order by ara.ModifiedDate desc limit 1
                    ) = 203
                ) then
                203 
            else
                201 
            end as ApprovalStatus
        , case 
            when (
                    t.CreatedDate = t.ModifiedDate
                    and 
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is null
                ) then
                case when p_language = 'zh-TW' then
                    'Not entered'
                when p_language = 'zh-CN' then
                    'Not entered'
                else
                    'Not Started'
                end
            when (
                    t.CreatedDate <> t.ModifiedDate
                    and 
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is null
                ) then
                case when p_language = 'zh-TW' then
                    'In-progress'
                when p_language = 'zh-CN' then
                    'In-progress'
                else
                    'In-progress'
                end
            when (
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is not null
                    and

                    (
                        select ara.ApprovalStatus from `approval_request_approvers` as ara
                        where ara.ApprovalRequestID = rt.ApprovalRequestID and ara.IsDeleted = 0
                        order by ara.ModifiedDate desc limit 1
                    ) = 202
                ) then
                case when p_language = 'zh-TW' then
                    'Approved'
                when p_language = 'zh-CN' then
                    'Approved'
                else
                    'Approved'
                end
            when (
                    rt.ApprovalRequestID is not null
                    and

                    (
                        select ara.ApprovalStatus from `approval_request_approvers` as ara
                        where ara.ApprovalRequestID = rt.ApprovalRequestID and ara.IsDeleted = 0
                        order by ara.ModifiedDate desc limit 1
                    ) = 203
                ) then
                case when p_language = 'zh-TW' then
                    'Rejected'
                when p_language = 'zh-CN' then
                    'Rejected'
                else
                    'Rejected'
                end
            else
                case when p_language = 'zh-TW' then
                    'Waiting for Approval'
                when p_language = 'zh-CN' then
                    'Waiting for Approval'
                else
                    'Waiting for Approval'
                end
            end as ApprovalStatusText
        , rt.ApprovalRequestID
    from
        `tasks` as t
        left join `delegations` as d on t.DelegationID = d.id
        left join `approval_request_tasks` as rt on rt.TaskID = t.id and rt.CreatedDate = 
            (
                select max(art2.CreatedDate) from `approval_request_tasks` as art2 where art2.TaskID = t.id
            )
        left join `approval_requests` as ar on rt.ApprovalRequestID = ar.id
    where
        t.IsDeleted = 0
        and (p_ids is null or p_ids = '' or FIND_IN_SET(t.id, p_ids))
        and (
            p_taskName is null or p_taskName = '' or 
            (
                case when (select count(lbl.id) from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = t.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'tasks' and lbl.ColumnName = 'TaskName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language and lbl.IsDeleted = 0) > 0 then
                    (select content from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = t.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'tasks' and lbl.ColumnName = 'TaskName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language and lbl.IsDeleted = 0 limit 1)
                else
                    t.TaskName
                end  like p_taskName
            )
            )
        and (p_delegationName is null or d.DelegationName like p_delegationName)
        and (
                p_locationIDs is null or p_locationIDs = ''
                or
                (
                    select count(*) 
                    from 
                        `tasks_details` as td
                        left join `usage` as u on td.ObjectID = u.id and td.ObjectType = 'usage'
                        left join `usage_descriptive` as ud on td.ObjectID = ud.id and td.ObjectType = 'descriptive'
                    where 
                        td.TaskID = t.id
                        and 
                        (
                            FIND_IN_SET(u.LocationID, p_locationIDs)
                            or
                            FIND_IN_SET(ud.LocationID, p_locationIDs)
                        )
                ) > 0
            )
        and (
                (
                    (p_assignedToUsers is null or p_assignedToUsers = '')
                    and
                    (p_assignedToGroups is null or p_assignedToGroups = '')
                )
                or
                (
                    (select count(*) from tasks_assignees as ta where 
                        ta.TaskID = t.id and ta.AssignedToObjectType = 'User'
                        and FIND_IN_SET(ta.AssignedToObjectID, p_assignedToUsers)) > 0
                )
                or
                (
                    (select count(*) from tasks_assignees as ta where 
                        ta.TaskID = t.id and ta.AssignedToObjectType = 'Group'
                        and FIND_IN_SET(ta.AssignedToObjectID, p_assignedToGroups)) > 0
                )
            )
        and (
                (p_dueDateFrom is null and p_dueDateTo is null)
                or
                (
                    (p_dueDateFrom is not null and p_dueDateFrom <= t.DueDate)
                    and
                    (p_dueDateTo is not null and p_dueDateTo >= t.DueDate)
                )
                or
                (p_dueDateFrom is null and p_dueDateTo is not null and p_dueDateTo >= t.DueDate)
                or
                (p_dueDateFrom is not null and p_dueDateTo is null and p_dueDateFrom <= t.DueDate)
            )
        and (p_createdBy is null or p_createdBy = '' or d.CreatedBy = p_createdBy)
        and (
                (
                    (p_createdDateFrom is not null and p_createdDateFrom <= t.CreatedDate)
                    and
                    (p_createdDateTo is not null and p_createdDateTo >= t.CreatedDate)
                )
                or
                (p_createdDateFrom is null and p_createdDateTo is null)
            )
        and (
                (p_statuses is null or p_statuses = '' or FIND_IN_SET(200, p_statuses))
                or
                case 
                    when (
                            t.CreatedDate = t.ModifiedDate
                            and
                            rt.ApprovalRequestID is null
                        ) then
                        FIND_IN_SET(204, p_statuses) 
                    when (
                            t.CreatedDate <> t.ModifiedDate
                            and
                            rt.ApprovalRequestID is null
                        ) then
                        FIND_IN_SET(205, p_statuses) 
                    when 

                        (
                            select ara.ApprovalStatus from `approval_request_approvers` as ara
                            where ara.ApprovalRequestID = rt.ApprovalRequestID and ara.IsDeleted = 0
                            order by ara.ModifiedDate desc limit 1
                        ) = 202
                        then
                        FIND_IN_SET(202, p_statuses) 
                    when

                        (
                            select ara.ApprovalStatus from `approval_request_approvers` as ara
                            where ara.ApprovalRequestID = rt.ApprovalRequestID and ara.IsDeleted = 0
                            order by ara.ModifiedDate desc limit 1
                        ) = 203
                        then
                        FIND_IN_SET(203, p_statuses) 
                    else
                        FIND_IN_SET(201, p_statuses) 
                    end
            )
        and (p_delegationIDs is null or p_delegationIDs = '' or FIND_IN_SET(t.DelegationID, p_delegationIDs))
    order by
        d.DelegationName, t.DueDate, t.TaskName
;
END
```

Here is the explain result

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                             | key     | key_len | ref                                    | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | t     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   | 1670 | 3.33     | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | d     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Index1                            | PRIMARY | 4       | pccw_iesg.t.DelegationID               | 1    | 11.11    | Using where                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | rt    | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   | 1340 | 100.00   | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | ar    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Index1                            | PRIMARY | 4       | pccw_iesg.rt.ApprovalRequestID         | 1    | 100.00   | NULL                                               |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 17 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ara   | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.rt.ApprovalRequestID         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index; Using filesort           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 16 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ara   | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.rt.ApprovalRequestID         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index; Using filesort           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 15 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ta    | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.t.id                         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index                           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 14 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ta    | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.t.id                         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index                           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 13 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | td    | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.t.id                         | 73   | 100.00   | Using index                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 13 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | u     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                   | PRIMARY | 4       | pccw_iesg.td.ObjectID                  | 1    | 100.00   | Using where                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 13 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ud    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                   | PRIMARY | 4       | pccw_iesg.td.ObjectID                  | 1    | 100.00   | Using where                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 12 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lbl   | NULL       | ref    | Index1,index2,index3,index4,index5,index6 | Index1  | 645     | const,pccw_iesg.t.id,const,const,const | 1    | 100.00   | NULL                                               |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 11 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lbl   | NULL       | ref    | Index1,index2,index3,index4,index5,index6 | Index1  | 645     | const,pccw_iesg.t.id,const,const,const | 1    | 100.00   | Using index                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | art2  | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   | 1340 | 10.00    | Using where                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 9  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ara   | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.rt.ApprovalRequestID         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index; Using filesort           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 8  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ara   | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.rt.ApprovalRequestID         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index; Using filesort           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 7  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ara   | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.rt.ApprovalRequestID         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index; Using filesort           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 6  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ara   | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.rt.ApprovalRequestID         | 1    | 10.00    | Using where; Using index; Using filesort           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 5  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | td    | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.t.id                         | 73   | 100.00   | Using index                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 4  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | td    | NULL       | ref    | Index1                                    | Index1  | 4       | pccw_iesg.t.id                         | 73   | 100.00   | Using index                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lbl   | NULL       | ref    | Index1,index2,index3,index4,index5,index6 | Index1  | 645     | const,pccw_iesg.t.id,const,const,const | 1    | 100.00   | NULL                                               |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lbl   | NULL       | ref    | Index1,index2,index3,index4,index5,index6 | Index1  | 645     | const,pccw_iesg.t.id,const,const,const | 1    | 100.00   | Using index                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Use = instead of like or find_in_set if that's an option